# Web Api Help Page route

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I was recently tasked with fixing one of our Help Pages that had gone down. I hadn't ever worked on one before, so I jumped in and started playing around with it. I noticed we had this route set up for the Help Page:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "HelpPage_Default",
            "api/v1/Help/{action}/{apiId}",
            new { controller = "Help", action = "Index", apiId = UrlParameter.Optional });

        HelpPageConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    }
```

I compared it to another working Help Page route and found the url to be different. I changed the url to

```
"Help/{action}/{apiId}"
```

and it worked. I've done some research online ([this helped](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/creating-api-help-pages)) but still fail to understand why changing the url would make any difference on whether that page would be hit. It would make sense to me that if I went to mydomain.com/api/v1/Help that I would still hit the help page with the original url.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: when you say changed url do you mean ""api/v1/Help/{action}/{apiId}", to ""Help/{action}/{apiId}" this?

note "api/v1/..." route pattern is specially for asp.net web api not for a MVC page.

Comment: @Prashant  Affirmative, that is the change that I made. Can you elaborate?

Comment: route what you have "api/v1/Help/{action}/{apiId}" this is wrong because format of the route should be [Controller]/[Action]/[Id] and your controller is Help not "api/v1" .

And to answer your question to your question of "mydomain.com/api/v1/Help" this url hitting the help page, yes it will if you give "help/{action}/apidid" url in the route.

api/v1 till here its your IIS virtual directory setup not your application configuration.

Comment: OK, thank you for the information! If you add it as an answer, I will gladly mark it as "the answer" to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route what you have "api/v1/Help/{action}/{apiId}" this is wrong because format of the route should be [Controller]/[Action]/[Id] and your controller is Help not "api/v1" .

And to answer your question to "mydomain.com/api/v1/Help" this url hitting the help page, yes it will if you give "help/{action}/apidid" url in the route.

"api/v1" till here its your IIS virtual directory setup not a route in your application configuration.